# How can I display 2 different panels at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, panel, layout-manager

My first panel's layout is BorderLayout and my second panel's layout is GridBagLayout. I don't know how to show them both at the same time.

I already tried adding two panels to on another panel.

Comment: I guess as it was unclear that there are *additional* requirements, the low quality of this question wasn't obvious. It's valid to ask how you can display both panels - that just wasn't all there was to it.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Adding both to another panel is the way to go! But you have to make the right choice of `LayoutManager` for this "parent" panel. Let me give you an example:

The `JFrame`'s content pane (where you add all your `Component`s to) can be setup with a `LayoutManager` of your choice. See this runnable example, which creates two `JPanel`s of 100x100 pixels in different colors. The panels are using the `LayoutManager`s you mentioned, but the main content pane of the `JFrame` is set to a `BoxLayout` (horizontal, but you can also set it to vertical!).

You can do this to any other panel, too. A `panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));` is enough. The below example just uses the content pane, but you can adapt it to your needs:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TwoPanels extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Dimension DEFAULT_DIMENSION = new Dimension(100, 100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TwoPanels();
    }

    public TwoPanels() {
        //create panel 1
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_DIMENSION);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);

        //create panel 2
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel2.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_DIMENSION);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        //set content pane layout
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        //add to content pane
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);

        //setup and display window
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** It's a little unclear from your question that you actually want to *stack overlaying panels*. You might find what you need here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: How can I add the second panel on top of the first panel?

Comment: Just use `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` instead of `BoxLayout.X_AXIS`. And don't forget to add them in the right order.

Comment: I mean adding a panel behind another panel.

Comment: Behind? So one panel is hidden by the other one? You can just go with `panel1.setVisible(false)` to only have `panel2` and vice versa.

Comment: I wanted to make both visible. Is that possible? Like the first panel is just a background.

Comment: OK, i didn't know that you want them to stack. You should **say that in your question!** Look at the link I added t my answer. It shows you how to use layered panes.

Comment: @mumpitz The question was not stated clearly enough to provide an appropriate answer ( https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mumpitz )